# How can i show required field validator error message in to associated textbox?

Tags: asp.net

I have one text box on that text box i am using required field validation.
If text box is empty then i want to show in the text box "Please enter some text", and if something is in text box then i want to check that text box text is valid email id or not if not then i want to show inside text box "Please enter valid email id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can carry out the following using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function CheckEmail()
{
    var $email = $("#<%=EmailText.ClientID %>");

    if ($email.val().length) {
        if (!IsEmailValid($email.val()))
            $email.val("Please enter a valid email address");
    }
    else {
        $email.val("Please enter some text.");
    }
}    

function IsEmailValid(inputvalue) 
{
    var pattern=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;

    if(pattern.test(inputvalue)) {
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="EmailText" Text="Please enter some text" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="CheckEmail()" />
```

Or you could use out of the box .NET validation using the RequiredFieldValidator and RegularExpressionValidator.

## Edit

Since the poster has stated client-side scripting cannot be used for validation, I've added server-side validation:

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (IsFormValid())
        {
        //Do something...
    }

}

private bool IsFormValid()
{
    bool isValid = true;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailText.Text))
    {
        EmailText.Text = "Please enter an email address";
        isValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(EmailAddress.Text, @"/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/"))
        {   
            EmailText.Text = "Email address not valid";
            isValid = false;    
        }
    
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a placeholder

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Please enter some text">
```

I believe you do need a jQuery plug in for that to work in Internet Explorer.

But I don't see why it should change to 'Please enter valid email id'

You could make it say 'Please enter valid email id' right at the start and add a validator script so people can't enter invalid emails.

```
function validateForm()

{
var x=document.forms["MyForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid email id");
  return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: one condition is here ,we cant use java script ,jquery,C# also. This is one the interview question ..............if possible then guide me or if not then tell reason ..........

Comment: @user1300780 You can't use javascript in a web project?? That's madness.

Comment: if java script is disabled then application will not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a reqiredfieldvalidator to check if the textbox is empty or not

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="yourTextBox" Text="This field is required" />
```

and to check for email validation you can use a RegularExpressionValidator to validate the input of the email

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="emailValidator" ControlToValidate="emailTextBox" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Text="please enter a valid email address" />
```

Comment: This required field validatior text i want to show in text box without using java script and jquery and c#.

Answer (score 0):

please use this sample:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter some text"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
    runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid emailid"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

RequiredFieldValidator validate empty textbox and then RegularExpressionValidator matches ValidationExpression, in this case it is emailid.

Comment: Hey guy please read my question again question is that this require field error message i want to show inside text box

Comment: inside the text boxt?? I'm not sure you can do using RequiredFieldValidator control, may be below(@sbhomra) answer is useful for that; in given javascript code try to assign your error message in textbox.

Answer (score 0):

For empty text validation use RequiredFieldValidator default functionality:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="requiredValidatorId" ControlToValidate="textBoxId" ErrorMessage="Please enter some text" />
```

And for input format or domain validation use server side logic like this:

```
if (!IsValidEmail(email))
{
    zoneRequiredValidatorId.Text = "Please enter valid email id";
    zoneRequiredValidatorId.IsValid = false;
}
else
if (...)
{
    zoneRequiredValidatorId.Text = "Validation error X";
    zoneRequiredValidatorId.IsValid = false;
}
...
```

Please note we are setting here the IsValid property to false.